# queue-worker:queue-worker_00: ERROR (spawn error) Laravel Supervisor CentOS 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, centos, supervisord, laravel-queue

I am trying to dispatch a job by `laravel queue:work` using supervisor in the live server (CentOS 7). Supervisor is running but the job is not processing. I am getting following error:

[image]

My worker file is :

```
[program:queue-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/maomin/public_html/bvend.xyz/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3 --max-time=3600 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
user=apache
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/maomin/public_html/bvend.xyz/w.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

log file (/home/maomin/public_html/bvend.xyz/w.log) shows below error :

```
The "--max-time" option does not exist.
```

I have tried almost all google solution but no luck

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue by doing following:

removed `--max-time=3600` and replaced **'sqs'** with **'database'** as I am using database for queue job.

```
command=php /home/maomin/public_html/bvend.xyz/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3 --max-time=3600 --daemon
```

to

```
command=php /home/maomin/public_html/bvend.xyz/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
```